# Turn off chrome change password pop-up

Tags: google-chrome

I'm building a website using simple passwords like 'abc123'. Chrome pops up this message everytime I log in my website and is very annoying. I can't find ways to turn it off. All solutions I searched are about removing passwords settings.

Please let me know any ways to turn this pop up off. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I disable Chrome password check only for localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177201/can-i-disable-chrome-password-check-only-for-localhost)

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome 122, navigate to settings, choose Privacy and security from the sidebar, then select Security from the list. Look for "**Warn you if passwords are exposed in a data breach**" and disable it.

Answer (score 2):

The duplicate target I linked ([Can I disable Chrome password check only for localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177201/can-i-disable-chrome-password-check-only-for-localhost)) only covers removing `type="password"` from your `input` elements.

As a more extreme measure, [this Google support thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23945619/how-to-disable-the-password-checkup-in-chrome?hl=en) proposes disabling the feature browser-wide. You should consider whether this is a good solution for your other browsing habits before turning it off to improve the development experience.

To turn off this feature:

1. Go to Chrome settings and go to Sync and Google services.
2. Turn off **Warn you if passwords are exposed in a data breach**.

Comment: An alternative may be keeping a separate "Developer" chrome profile where you disable such security features (or things like caching), so you have a different context from "browsing the web" vs. "web development".